# How to detect when media player is done playing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This may me a simple question, but how do I detect when **MPMediaPlayer** is done playing in Swift 4?

Comment: It probably has delegate methods. You'll want to implement those. Do you have a link to the Framework you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track this using NSNotificationCenter.

```
func play(url: NSURL) {
 let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerDidFinishPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: item)

 let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
 player.play()
}

 func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
     // Your code here
 }
```

Comment: I'm not using AVPlayer, just MPMediaPlayer, although I am looking to switch to AVPlayer in the future. Therefore I am passing MPMediaItem into my play function. For future reference, NSNotificationCenter has been renamed NotificationCenter. :)

Comment: And defaultCenter is now default.